# Declare variable in Grafana query from dashboard variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, grafana, dashboard, grafana-variable

I am using a table visualization in Grafana and I want to filter the content of the table with a variable called "PC", of type query, showing a list of PC names.

The SQL sentence that I am using is the following:

```sql
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @PC AS NVARCHAR(255) = $PC;
DECLARE @pcFilter AS NVARCHAR(255) = '%' + @PC + '%'

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(PC)
                   FROM DATOS_GENERALES DG INNER JOIN OPERACION_MANUAL OM ON DG.RefId = OM.RefId
                   WHERE TimeStamp_UTC IS NOT NULL AND PC LIKE @pcFilter
                        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                        ,1,1,'')

SET @query = 'SELECT Fecha, ' + @cols + ' FROM
            (SELECT PC, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(8), TimeStamp_UTC, 112) AS Fecha, 
            (TiempoTest + 2 * Tiempo)/3600 AS TiempoTotal
            FROM DATOS_GENERALES DG INNER JOIN OPERACION_MANUAL OM ON DG.RefId = OM.RefId
            WHERE TimeStamp_UTC IS NOT NULL AND PC LIKE @pcFilter) AS A
            PIVOT
            (
                SUM(TiempoTotal) FOR PC IN (' + @cols + ')
            ) AS P
            ORDER BY Fecha DESC'
/* Original execution
EXECUTE(@query); 
*/
-- Currently using execution
EXECUTE sp_executesql @query, N'@pcFilter nvarchar(255)', @pcFilter = @pcFilter
```

The variable `pcFilter` is declared in order to take the value of the Grafana's dashboard variable `PC` and then added to the `WHERE` conditions.

Without declaring the variable and including the `WHERE` condition the table is correctly shown, but with the code from above I get this error:

```
db query error: mssql: Must declare the scalar variable "@pcFilter".
```

Am I declaring in a wrong way this variable?
If so, how should I do it?

Comment: Have you checked if this query (with `$PC` manually substituted by its value from Grafana) works using some db client? Could you also share the initial query?

Comment: Manually subsituting `$PC` still does not work.

Comment: The @query has @pcFilter which is not declared anywhere when `EXECUTE(@query)`..similar to `EXECUTE('select @pcFilter')`. You could use sp_executesql to execute the @query and declare @pcFilter...`exec sp_executesql @query, N'@pcFilter nvarchar(255)', @pcFilter = @pcFilter`

Comment: Still getting the same error. The query inspector shows this result once the filtering is applied to choose 3 different PCs: `DECLARE @PC AS NVARCHAR(255) = 'LPHQ0141','LPHQ0308','PCHQ0395'; DECLARE @pcFilter AS NVARCHAR(255) = '%' + @PC + '%';`

Answer (score 0):

Problem lies within your generated statement.

Basically, at the last line of script you provided dbms tries so execute something like

```sql
SELECT Fecha, col1, col2, col3 FROM
            (SELECT PC, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(8), TimeStamp_UTC, 112) AS Fecha, 
            (TiempoTest + 2 * Tiempo)/3600 AS TiempoTotal
            FROM DATOS_GENERALES DG INNER JOIN OPERACION_MANUAL OM ON DG.RefId = OM.RefId
            WHERE TimeStamp_UTC IS NOT NULL AND PC LIKE @pcFilter) AS A
            PIVOT
            (
                SUM(TiempoTotal) FOR PC IN (col1, col2, col3)
            ) AS P
            ORDER BY Fecha DESC
```

but variable `@pcFilter` is undeclared here (because `EXECUTE` statement has it's own scope).

You either need to pass a declaration of `@pcFilter` into your `@query`, or better yet change line

```
WHERE TimeStamp_UTC IS NOT NULL AND PC LIKE @pcFilter) AS A
```

to

```
WHERE TimeStamp_UTC IS NOT NULL AND PC LIKE ''' + @pcFilter + ''') AS A
```

Comment: Same result when substituting `@pcFilter` by `''' + @pcFilter + '''` in `@query`

Comment: Could you print generated this way query and try execute it independently?

Comment: Sure. `DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @PC AS NVARCHAR(255) = $PC;
DECLARE @pcFilter AS NVARCHAR(255) = '%' + @PC + '%';

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(PC) FROM DATOS_GENERALES DG INNER JOIN OPERACION_MANUAL OM ON DG.RefId = OM.RefId WHERE TimeStamp_UTC IS NOT NULL AND PC LIKE @pcFilter FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'')`...

Comment: ...`SET @query = 'SELECT Fecha, ' + @cols + ' FROM (SELECT PC, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(8), TimeStamp_UTC, 112) AS Fecha, (TiempoTest + 
2*Tiempo)/3600 AS TiempoTotal FROM DATOS_GENERALES DG INNER JOIN OPERACION_MANUAL OM ON DG.RefId = OM.RefId WHERE TimeStamp_UTC IS NOT NULL AND PC LIKE ''' + @pcFilter + ''') AS A PIVOT (SUM(TiempoTotal) FOR PC IN (' + @cols + ')) AS P ORDER BY Fecha DESC' EXECUTE sp_executesql @query, N'@pcFilter nvarchar(255)', @pcFilter = @pcFilter`

Comment: I mean instead of `EXECUTE` use `Print` to see what `@query` is generated. And then take this query and execute it yourself.

Comment: When substituting manually one value in `$PC` (for example `DECLARE @PC AS NVARCHAR(255) = 'LPHQ0141'`) it prints the query as expected and also executing the query works. However, when adding manually another value in the second line, when declaring `@PC`, it fails.